# Error initializing driver method - undefined local variable

Tags: ruby, selenium, rubygems, automated-tests, capybara

In my test automation project, I am using ruby with capybara, cucumber and selenium.
(I already have devkit installed and chrome is starting normally)

When looking for an element in the site to select it, I am using the method `driver.findElement (By.xpath (.... etc")`, but when executing cucumber, it is indicating the following error:

I already removed and reinstalled the `selenium-webdriver` gem but it did not resolve.

Can someone help me in resolving why `WebDriver` does not seem to be valid in this context?

**code example**

> (finding button logout using tag img, because the element don't have name or id)

`After('@logout') do
    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='/Portal/img/user.png']"));
    element.click
end`

**Result cucumber execution**

Feature: Login
Description feature

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60121/devtools/browser/c0bacc6e-697a-4614-b82c-eb324d587df5
  @logout
  Scenario: Login_OK                                           # features/support/login.feature:14
    Given that i access the main portal page HRP           # features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:1
    When do login using "abc123" and "abc123password" # features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:5
    Then system do login                                      # features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:10
    And show message "Welcome to Portal."            # features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:14
      undefined local variable or method `driver' for # (NameError)
      ./features/support/hooks.rb:4:in `After'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/support/login.feature:14 # Scenario: Login_OK

1 scenario (1 failed)
4 steps (4 passed)
0m5.457s

Comment: Include a code sample, the specific code referenced by the error, and the actual stacktrace.

Comment: You’ve tagged this question with Capybara but then are attempting to call webdriver directly rather than using Capybara, is there a reason for this?

Comment: Forgive me for not knowing how to differentiate the subjects.
I started my studies in automation tests 3 days ago, that's why i mark capybara on the subject of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Capybara with Cucumber in a standard setup then you shouldn't be really ever be calling the selenium webdriver instance directly - `driver` (except for in some very rare circumstances). Instead you should be using the Capybara methods.  What is available in your `After` hook depends on exactly how where you've `include`ed what but one of these will probably be avaialble

```
After('@logout') do
  element = page.find(:xpath, ".//img[@src='/Portal/img/user.png']"));
  element.click
end
```

or

```
After('@logout') do
  element = Capybara.current_session.findElement(:xpath, ".//img[@src='/Portal/img/user.png']");
  element.click
end
```

Note: there is probably a better way to locate the logout button than an XPath on the contained images source, but without seeing the HTML of the button it's impossible to say for sure (for instance, Capybaras button finder will match against the `alt` attribute of an img element nested inside a <button> element)

Comment: The HTML of the button is:

`<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                            <img alt="" src="/Portal/img/user.png" style="width:35px;height:35px;">
                            <span class="username">Pedro</span>
                            <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>`

Comment: From a semantic perspective that element really should be a <button> element and not an <a> since it's not a link to anything. Also you should always specify an alt attribute (non-blank) for images that users interact with for accessibility reasons (screen readers, etc). If you leave it as an <a> but add an actual alt attribute then you could just do `Capybara.current_session.click_link('the value of the alt attribute')`